# Can send but cant receive emails using Godaddy office 365

Tags: email, outlook, office365

```
 <add key="Host" value="relay-hosting.secureserver.net"/>
    <add key="EnableSsl" value="false"/>
    <add key="UserName" value="contact@xxx.com"/>
    <add key="Password" value="xxxx"/>
    <add key="Port" value="25"/>


The response from the remote server was:
550 5.1.1 <contact@xxxx.com> Recipient not found. <http://x.co/irbounce>
```

I do not what what the issue is or why it cant be found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was making use of the workspace email earlier. i had to change the mx record to work with office 365

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-DNS-records-at-GoDaddy-for-Office-365-f40a9185-b6d5-4a80-bb31-aa3bb0cab48a#BKMK_add_MX